# Typeahead in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement autocomplete in Angular. I am getting my data from following service (returns a string array with autocomplete values):

```
this.apiService.getAutoComplete(query).subscribe((data) => {  
   return data;
})
```

I am new to Angular so I may be on the wrong path. But I found these samples, it looks like a good match to my need:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead

My problem is that the samples are based on a static array, and I tried for some time now to change it to async data. But with no luck. I tried going for the async sample and changed following fucntion, but didnt work:

```
getStatesAsObservable(token: string): Observable<any> {       
  return of(
    this.apiService.getAutoComplete('ja').subscribe((data) => {  
      return data;
    })
  );
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>

<input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
       [typeaheadAsync]="true"
       [typeahead]="dataSource"
       (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
       [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
       placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
       class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="typeaheadLoading">Loading</div>
```

But to be honest I have no idea where to change the code in the chain, and if I am using the right sample (where auto comeplete is not based on fix array). All input are welcome.

Comment: post your html code too

Comment: don't subscribe if you are trying to return an observable...

Comment: HTML added. Thanks for your replies. HTML added. @Ajt how do I then consume my service? I am new to Angular so not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: There is even a sample on how to deal with async data :) https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead#async-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @ngez library which has an autocomplete component:
https://ngez-platform.firebaseapp.com/#/core/autocomplete

component.html

```
<input type="text" [ngezAutocomplete]="ngezAutocomplete">

<ngez-autocomplete #ngezAutocomplete>
    <ngez-autocomplete-option [value]="value" *ngFor="let value of data">
        {{value}}
    </ngez-autocomplete-option>
</ngez-autocomplete>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NgEzAutocompleteDirective } from "@ngez/core";
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

    data: string[];

    @ViewChild(NgEzAutocompleteDirective) autocomplete: NgEzAutocompleteDirective;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.autocomplete.text$
            .pipe(
                 switchMap(query => this.apiService.getAutoComplete(query))
             )
            .subscribe(data=> {
                this.data = data
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using the CoreUI which have the ngx-bootstrap installed allready. Is there any reason you would not use this framework an suggest ngez? If I cant get the other to work I will give it a try.

Comment: @ThomasSegato, you can still use the bootstrap input with the ngez autocomplete. Look at the demo.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.